# Nginx: How can I provide variable for paths in nginx configuration?

Tags: deployment, nginx, amazon-ec2

- I have a web application which I test locally and deploy on EC2 instance
- I am using **local** nginx configuration which looks like as

> ```
> location /static/ {       alias /home/me/code/p/python/myapp/static/;
>     # if asset versioning is used
>     if ($query_string) {
>         expires max;
>     }
> }     location /templates/ {      alias /home/me/code/p/python/app/templates/;
>     # if asset versioning is used
>     if ($query_string) {
>         expires max;
>     }
> }
> ```

On EC2 instance, the only thing that would change is the path, e.g.

`/home/me/code/p/python/myapp/static/` to `/User/ubuntu/code/p/python/myapp/static/`

- To make this happen I change the configuration to look like

`~/code/p/python/myapp/static/`

but this didn't work, it shows the path

`/etc/nginx/~/code/p/python/myapp/static/`

which is not right

**Question**
- Is it possible to include environment variables in nginx conf?

**What I want**
- Nginx conf, which can read variables on specific machines to create paths, so that I don't have to change it per machine and code is reusable

Thank you

Comment: rather than changing your production server, how about setting up symlinks on your computer to match your server? lots of benefits in keeping paths the same if possible

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

1. As suggested above, symlinking is a really good way of making paths match on machines, while keeping code in one place. A symbolic link basically is an alias; if /link is a symlink for /file, when you ask for /link, you'll get /file.

   ```
   ln -s /file /link
   ```
2. Using include statements. In nginx, you can `include variables.conf;`. E.g.

   nginx.conf:

   ```
   include variables.conf

   ...

   http {
      listen $port;
      ... 
   }
   ```

   variables.conf:

   ```
   set $foo "Something";
   set $bar "Else";
   set $port 80;
   ```